# I'm trying to create and call a function to reverse a string and remove the integer before the decimal point

Tags: python

So I have been around and around this for ages and I know I am making a newbie error. I just can't figure out what it is. When I think I have it resolved and there are no errors it still doesn't work when I run it. It will ask for the inputs but return nothing.

I did manage to get the string to return it backwards once so I know that the code works there and I tried the float part separately and that worked but I can't figure out how to put them together.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. If you could explain where I am going wrong that would be amazing too. Thanks!

```
def my_function(my_string, my_float):
    try:
        my_float = float(my_float)
    except NameError:
        print("That's not a float, try using numbers with a decimal point in the middle of them.")

    number = str(my_float)
    if 'e-' in number:
        my_float = format(float(number),
                          '.%df' % (len(number.split(".")[1].split("e-")[0]) + int(number.split('e-')[1])))
    elif "." in number:
        my_float = number.split(".")[1]
        return my_float
    print("your float minus the integer is: ", my_float)
    new_string = ""
    i = len(my_string) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        new_string = new_string + my_string[i]
        i = i - 1
    print("Your string backwards reads: " + new_string)


print("Please enter a string: ")
mystring = input()
print("Please enter a float number: ")
myfloat = input()
my_function(mystring, myfloat)
```

Comment: Can you explain ` I can't figure out how to put them together` with some examples including imput and expected output?

Comment: What is the intention of using the `except NameError:`

Comment: It looks like your code is doing two things -- reversing a string, and removing digits before a decimal point for a float. Maybe write two functions: one for the first part and one for the second. Then write some test cases so you can see what's working and what's not.

Comment: A test case can be as simple as `assert my_reverse("hello") == "olleh"`. If such an assert fails, you then have something to start a debugging session.

Comment: Since you are converting input to `float` this condition `elif "." in number:` will always be true and if it doesn't goes to the first if condition. Hence you see no output as it is returning the number

Comment: Without exactly pinpointing what your code is supposed to do, it is hard for us to help you, however you should look into the `return my_float` line : it prematurely end your function before the string parts,

Comment: @Ritwik G I was asked to validate that a float was entered.

Comment: @RitwikG `1e+20` is a float that does not contain a decimal point when converted to a string.

Comment: So I need to create a Python function that receives two input parameters, the first one is a string value and the second one is a float number. The string should be revered and printed and the float should only have the decimal part so 1.99234 becomes .99234

Comment: For handling invalid float you need to except `ValueError`: Try in an interpreter with invalid value to check the error thrown

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I really need a lot more work but I appreciate the speed at which you all helped and I learned more here than an hour or two of online tab trawling.

Comment: Thank you @RitwikG, You were right about the NameError needing to be ValueError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this might do the trick for you:

```py
def my_function(my_string, my_float):
    try:
        my_float = '.' + ('%f' % float(my_float)).split('.')[1]
        print("your float minus the integer is: ", my_float)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a float, try using numbers with a decimal point in the middle of them.")
    print("Your string backwards reads: " + ''.join(reversed(my_string)))
```

Comment: Well now. That's taken the steam out of my sails. A simple way to solve an uncomplicated problem. Thank you! So in the float part, you just told it to remove everything one to the left of the decimal? I don't know why I overcomplicate things.

Comment: The float part does exactly what you tried to do, but in a single line. And correctly. ;) Python can be very concise, which I've come to appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the return statement inside the function

```
elif "." in number:
    my_float = number.split(".")[1]
    return my_float
```

otherwise, whenever a floating number is passed, that return will be triggered and you won't get any output

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni. I see that now. It seems painfully obvious but I'm just learning.

Comment: Nothing is obvious until you see it. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe I can help you:

```
string1 = "teststring"
stringReversed = string1[::-1]

floatInput = 12.34
floatStr = str(floatInput)
stuffAfterDecimalPoint = floatStr.split(".")[1]
combinedStrings = stringReversed + stuffAfterDecimalPoint
```

Comment: I appreciate your help here. Yeah I can see where I really overcomplicated it above. Your approach is a lot cleaner. Thanks again.